# PHP - Get amount of open files of current process

Tags: php, php-8

For monitoring purposes, I want to forward the amount of open files of the current process to our monitoring tool. In shell, the following command can be executed to get the desired information: `ls /proc/PROCES_ID/fd | wc -l` where PROCES_ID is the current process id. Is there a way to get this information natively in PHP?

Comment: you can `exec()` this  shell command in the php and get the responses, but doing it using bash should be the preferred way as spawning a shell command from within php script may consume more resources that can pile if you use it in high traffic endpoint

Comment: I would agree with what @RakibulHaq suggests, doing this outside of the script seems way better. if you wanted to to do this via exec() inside the PHP script though, you can get hold of the process ID via posix_* family of fucntions if they are enabled. I wouldn't know a _native_ way to get the open files within.

Comment: I think the best you can do with native PHP is [get_included_files](https://www.php.net/get_included_files), which gives you any files opened with `require|include`. Which doesn't include autoloaded classes, `file_get_contents` etc.

Comment: @RakibulHaq Unfortunately, I don't have bash available in my Docker container. I'll therefore use shell. It is a proces managed by supervisord. Not necessarily high traffic so save to say I won't experience any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run any shell commands from within php script and get the output:

---

From [PHP manual on exec() command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec(string $command, array &$output = null, int &$result_code = null): string|false
```

For your command:

```
$output = []; // this array will hold whatever the output from the bash command
$result_code = null; // this will give you the result code returned, if needed
$command = '/proc/PROCES_ID/fd | wc -l'; // command to be run in the bash
exec($command, &$output, &$result_code);

//now you can look into $output array variable for the values returned from the above command
print_r($output);
```

But as mentioned in the comment, using bash script over php should be preferred if feasible.

Comment: The example code is not working as is, as you do not provide the actual process id in the command.